# Create sqlite database through android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-cursor

I believe with the following code, I am able to create a database, create a table, and insert the sensor values inside.

This line create a db
-> super(context, "sensor.sqlite", null, 1);
in data/data/example.com.sensor/databases/sensor.sqlite

In the oncreate method, a table is created. 
In the insert method, a record will be inserted.

However when I check in ddms, the db is not even created. I found a data folder but there is no data/data folder.

Any idea why this happens?

```
package example.com.sensor;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Date;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class SqlController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;

    public SqlController(Context context) {
        super(context, "sensor.sqlite", null, 1);

        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
        this.onCreate(super.getReadableDatabase());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {


        String x = "CREATE TABLE [sport] ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,";
        x+=" [accx] REAL,";
        x+=" [accy] REAL,";
        x+=" [accz] REAL,";
        x+=" [geox] REAL,";
        x+=" [geoy] REAL,";
        x+=" [geoz] REAL,";
        x+=" [activity] TEXT,";
        x+=" [datetime] TIMESTAMP)";

        database.execSQL(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        onCreate(database);
    }

    public void insert(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println(database.getPath());

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("accx", queryValues.get("accx"));
        values.put("accy", queryValues.get("accy"));
        values.put("accz", queryValues.get("accz"));
        values.put("geox", queryValues.get("geox"));
        values.put("geoy", queryValues.get("geoy"));
        values.put("geoz", queryValues.get("geoz"));
        values.put("activity", queryValues.get("activity"));
        values.put("datetime", new Date().toString());
        database.insert("sport", null, values);
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged through the code at all? Are your methods actually called? Are you sure you're meant to call `onCreate` rather than it being called automatically for you?

Comment: Its me again :).  This is the same issue as your last post.  Your phone is not rooted and `adb` (and thus `ddms`) does not have permission to read the /data/data folders.  The folders do exist, you just don't have permission to open them.

Comment: Can I save to sd card instead? tqs.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  For KitKat and above, be sure to use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest.

Comment: However, I think you said is incorrect, I still able to create database, create table and insert record. What I do not know is where I store the db.

Comment: Hi, Jon Socket -> Yes there is an exception happen while create table. The exception is table was exist. I have add a try-catch on it. Now my problem is I do not know where the sensor.sqlite is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that you are getting is because you are calling `this.onCreate(super.getReadableDatabase());` directly in the constructor.  There is no need to call `onCreate()` directly, it is a callback that [will be called when the database file did not exist previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run/21881993#21881993).

There is no need to change the path that your database file gets written to, just leave it be.  As @pathfinderelite mentioned, it's written to internal storage of your app, which cannot be accessed unless you have a rooted device.

You state that you don't know where it's stored, but you **do** know where it's stored, you just don't have access to it, which is expected.

In order to verify the contents of your database, just to a simple `select` query, and log the results.

```
public void printAllActivities() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    System.out.println(database.getPath());

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from sport", null);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        int index = c.getColumnIndex("activity");
        String activity = c.getString(index);
        System.out.println("activity from database: " + activity);            

    }
    c.close();
    database.close();
}
```

Comment: @JimmyLee I just realized there was an error in the code, I had `cursor` instead of `c`, see the updated answer.